# Where to set Google Cast's custom receiver app ID [Connect SDK]

Tags: television

In Google Cast SDK, I am able to specify the custom receiver app ID by calling:

```
[self.deviceManager launchApplication:kReceiverAppID];
```

Where in Connect SDK can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Connect SDK [documentation](http://connectsdk.com/docs/ios/beam-web-apps/):

```
NSString *webAppId;

if ([_device serviceWithName:@"webOS TV"])
    webAppId = @"5G7328DE";
else if ([_device serviceWithName:@"Chromecast"])
    webAppId = @"3E5106AB";

if (!webAppId)
    return;

[_device.webAppLauncher launchWebApp:webAppId success:^(WebAppSession *webAppSession) {
    NSLog(@"web app launch success");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"web app launch error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```